# Can I make a Slave Table for one Master Table like Master-Slave database replication?

Tags: sql-server

I have a sensitive table in SQL Server. And to prevent it from being updated with mistakes or deleted by others mistakenly, I want to create a Slave Table for it as a backup, like Master-Slave Database Replication. 
What parameter should I add or what function could I use?

Comment: I used a trigger to do this action, but it is too complex.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you on? I ask because Temporal Tables (SQL 2016+) or CDC SQL 2008+) might be an option. Also, you mentioned a trigger being too complex. In what way?

Comment: @BenThul My version is SQL Server 2016, you mean that I can use temporal table to make a slave table? Trigger is complex, cause I need to update all fields in backup table when master table update one  filed. Master Table have many fields, I cannot locate which filed is updated in Master Table, so I have to update all fields by trigger after updated.

Comment: Or any methods to get which filed is updated and the update value?

Comment: Either should work and both work (more or less) by the same mechanism. For the trigger, it should be as easy as insert into dbo.otherTable select *, getutcdate() as date_modified from deleted;` Which would allow your other table to have prior versions of the data and your live table having the current version. You should read up on temporal tables to see if they meet your need.